partial differential equation problem about the green function of heat conduction
how to  solve the equation：
$$
\left[\frac{\partial }{(\partial t)}-\kappa \frac{\partial ^2}{(\partial x)^2}\right]\varrho (x\pmb{,}t)\pmb{+}\frac{\kappa }{a^2}\frac{\partial
^2}{(\partial t)^2}\varrho (x\pmb{,}t)=\kappa \delta \left(x-x'\right)\delta \left(t-t'\right) { }\left(-\infty <x,x'<\infty ;t,t'>0;\epsilon
_0<a<\infty \right)\\
\varrho (x\pmb{,}0)=0,\frac{\partial }{(\partial t)}\varrho (x\pmb{,}0)=0\\
\text{the } \text{answer}:\varrho (x\pmb{,}t)=\frac{a}{2}J_0\left(\frac{a}{2\kappa }\sqrt{\left(x-x'\right)^2-a^2\left(t-t'\right)^2}\right)\exp \left[-\frac{a^2}{2\kappa
}\left(t'-t\right)\right]\times Θ \left[t-t'-\frac{\left| x-x'\right| }{a}\right]
$$
$$Θ \text{ is
Heaviside Theta function } $$

It's a wave equation by $\square = \partial_t^2 - \partial_x^2$ and the  fact, that $\rho =0, \partial_t \rho=0$ are provided as start conditions

Thanks to the answer, the standard heat conduction model simplifies the microscopic principle of molecular motion, and the second-order time differential operator should be used as a correction factor. At the same time, I found some careless mistakes in the formula, which have been corrected

Why do you complicate your notation using $\eta$ to represent the Heaviside Theta $(\Theta)$ function?

This is purely a personal habit. If you think it is not appropriate, I can modify it

I suggest that you do modify it. You should write clearly to the benefit of your readers.

It may be because of my habit of reading textbooks in the former Soviet Union. I am sorry for the confusion caused by this, and I have modified it

@Ipigandothergod, there had been a lot of high quality mathematics pumped out from the Soviets. And more from other mathematicians too. We learn and adapt.

you are right.I'm just a beginner and may not be comfortable with these latest signs

proof:firstly use Laplace's transform and get:
$$\frac{d^2\varrho (x\pmb{,}p)}{(dx)^2}-\left(\frac{p}{\kappa }+\frac{p^2}{a^2}\right)\varrho (x\pmb{,}t)=e^{-p\times t'}\delta \left(x-x'\right)\\$$
through the method of green function,we can get:
$$\varrho (p\pmb{,}t)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\frac{p^2}{a^2}+\frac{p}{\kappa }}}e^{-p\times t'}\times \text{Exp}\left[-\sqrt{\frac{p^2}{a^2}+\frac{p}{\kappa
}}\times \left| x-x'\right| \right]\\
=\frac{a}{2\sqrt{\left(p+\frac{a^2}{2\kappa }\right)^2-\frac{a^4}{4\kappa ^2}}}e^{-p\times t'}\times \text{Exp}\left[-\sqrt{\left(p+\frac{a^2}{2\kappa
}\right)^2-\frac{a^4}{4\kappa ^2}}\times \frac{\left| x-x'\right| }{a}\right]\\
=\frac{a}{2\sqrt{\left(p+\frac{a^2}{2\kappa }\right)^2-\frac{a^4}{4\kappa ^2}}}e^{-p\times t'}\times \text{Exp}\left[-\sqrt{\left(p+\frac{a^2}{2\kappa
}\right)^2-\frac{a^4}{4\kappa ^2}}\times \frac{\left| x-x'\right| }{a}\right]\\
=\frac{a}{2\sqrt{\left(p+\frac{a^2}{2\kappa }\right)^2+\left(\frac{i a^2}{2\kappa }\right)^2}}e^{-p\times t'}\times \text{Exp}\left[-\sqrt{\left(p+\frac{a^2}{2\kappa
}\right)^2+\left(\frac{i a^2}{2\kappa }\right)^2}\times \frac{\left| x-x'\right| }{a}\right]\\$$
according to Лаврентьев М.А.&Шабат.Методы теории функций комплексного переменного (I can not find the formula in many English's monographs.
If anyone can provide relevant literature,please inform me)
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{p^2+b^2}}e^{-\tau _0\sqrt{p^2+b^2}}=\mathcal{L}\left[J_0\left(b\sqrt{t^2-\tau _0{}^2}\right)\eta \left(t-\tau _0\right)\right]\\$$
or use usual sign:
$$\left.\mathcal{L}\left[J_0\left(b\sqrt{t^2-\tau _0{}^2}\right)\Theta \left(t-\tau _0\right)\right]\right]\\$$
using Laplace 's translation theorem and  delay theorem,We can easily eliminate the irregular factor：
$$F(p)e^{-p\times \tau }=\mathcal{L}[f(t-\tau )]\\
\\
F\left(p-p_0\right)=\mathcal{L}\left[f(t)e^{p_0t}\right]\\$$
therefore:$$F\left(p-p_0\right)e^{-p\times \tau }=\mathcal{L}\left[f(t-\tau )e^{p_0(t-\tau )}\right)\\$$
notice that:$$
p_0=-\frac{a^2}{2\kappa };\tau =t';\tau _0=\frac{\left| x-x'\right| }{a};b=\frac{i a^2}{2\kappa }\\
\\$$
$$\frac{a}{2\sqrt{\left(p+\frac{a^2}{2\kappa }\right)^2+\left(\frac{i a^2}{2\kappa }\right)^2}}e^{-p\times t'}\times \text{Exp}\left[-\sqrt{\left(p+\frac{a^2}{2\kappa
}\right)^2+\left(\frac{i a^2}{2\kappa }\right)^2}\times \frac{\left| x-x'\right| }{a}\right]\\
=\frac{a}{2}\mathcal{L}\left[J_0\left(\frac{i\times  a^2}{2\kappa }\sqrt{\left(t-t'\right)^2-\left(\frac{\left| x-x'\right| }{a}\right)^2}\right)\Theta
\left(\left(t-t'\right)-\frac{\left| x-x'\right| }{a}\right)\times \text{Exp}\left[-\frac{a^2}{2\kappa }\left(t-t'\right)\right]\right]=\mathcal{L}\left[\frac{a}{2}J_0\left(\frac{(-1)\times
 a}{2\kappa }\sqrt{\left| x-x'\right| ^2-a^2\left(t-t'\right)^2}\right)\Theta \left(\left(t-t'\right)-\frac{\left| x-x'\right| }{a}\right)\times
\text{Exp}\left[-\frac{a^2}{2\kappa }\left(t-t'\right)\right]\right] { } { }\\
\text{                                                                                }=\mathcal{L}\left[\frac{a}{2}J_0\left(\frac{ a}{2\kappa
}\sqrt{\left| x-x'\right| ^2-a^2\left(t-t'\right)^2}\right)\Theta \left(\left(t-t'\right)-\frac{\left| x-x'\right| }{a}\right)\times \text{Exp}\left[-\frac{a^2}{2\kappa
}\left(t-t'\right)\right]\right]\text{                                                                          }\square { } { } $$
